# Nav bar won't center in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm sorry for asking this question, but I've search through stack overflow for weeks and haven't been able to rectify my problem. My nav bar is left justified; I need it to center. I have tried applying margin: 0px auto; to every element within the hierarchy of the `<nav>` along with text-align: center; but nothing is centering it.

It's a Bootstrap 3 framework. Here's the code and my external CSS in addition to the bootstrap.min.css file:

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
}
.row.content {
  height: 450px
}
.sidenav {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  height: 100%;
}
footer {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px;
  font-family: "IM Fell DW Pica", serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .row.content {
    height: auto;
  }
}
#banner-img {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
header {
  background-color: #394650;
  /* background color of header */
}
nav {
  font-family: "IM Fell DW Pica", serif;
  /* font style of nav bar */
  font-size: 23px;
  /* font size of nav bar */
}
#myNavBar ul li {
  text-align: center;
}
/* FOR SMALL SCREENS */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    font-size: 40px;
    /* changes font size on smaller screens */
  }
  /* sets dimensions for embedded video on small screens */
  #intro-video-div {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
  }
  section h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  section p {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
/* FOR BIG SCREENS */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* sets dimensions for embedded video on larger screens */
  #intro-video-div {
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
  }
  section h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
  section p {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  #content-ads-holding-div {
    height: 750px;
  }
  .img-responsive {
    margin: auto;
  }
}
section,
h1,
p {
  font-family: "IM Fell DW Pica", serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: static;
}
#intro-video-div {
  margin: 0px auto;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
}
#intro-video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#nav-div-center,
#nav-ul {
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar-container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <div id="nav-div-center">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-ul">
          <li class="active" id="home">Home</li>
          <li id="episodes">Episodes</li>
          <li id="research">Research</li>
          <li id="store">Store</li>
          <li id="support">Support</li>
          <li id="communicate">Communicate</li>
          <li id="affiliations">Affiliations</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You can see the actual website at http://www.kspavia.com/bootstrap.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the below css to make navbar center.

```
@media (min-width: 768px){ 
  .navbar-nav{
      margin: 0 auto;
      float: none;
      display: table;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center the navigation you need to assign a width. A block level element will always expand as wide as it can.

```
#nav-ul {
  max-width: 780px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that div was left over from another idea I had. I just forgot to remove it after my attempt failed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you ultimately want to do (justify the links across the `nav` or center in the links in the `nav`) you simple have to change the display and float properties to do either.

*Note*: I adjusted the font size above 768px to prevent any links from overflowing on a reduced viewport.

Here are two working examples. *View at FullPage.*

**Distributed (justified) Links Example:**

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: "IM Fell DW Pica", serif;
  font-size: 22px;
}
/*Distributed Links Starts*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse > .container-fluid {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
/*Distributed Links Ends*/

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 20px 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active" id="home"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="episodes"><a href="#">Episodes</a>
        </li>
        <li id="research"><a href="#">Research</a>
        </li>
        <li id="store"><a href="#">Store</a>
        </li>
        <li id="support"><a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li id="communicate"><a href="#">Communicate</a>
        </li>
        <li id="affiliations"><a href="#">Affiliations</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Center Links Example:**

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-family: "IM Fell DW Pica", serif;
  font-size: 18px;
}
/*Centered Links Starts*/

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}
/*Centered Links Ends*/

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 40px;
    padding: 20px 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active" id="home"><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li id="episodes"><a href="#">Episodes</a>
        </li>
        <li id="research"><a href="#">Research</a>
        </li>
        <li id="store"><a href="#">Store</a>
        </li>
        <li id="support"><a href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li id="communicate"><a href="#">Communicate</a>
        </li>
        <li id="affiliations"><a href="#">Affiliations</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your navigation center aligned. Just update your existing  css **second-bootstrap-stylesheet.css** line no **119** as per below css:-

```
#nav-div-center, #nav-ul {
   width: 78%;
   float: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `.container` instead of `.container-fluid` if you want `.navbar` block to be on center or use apply styles:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){ 
  .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-nav > li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```